# How to put a date as a variable in a formula in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, formula

In the code, the date is 100% correct. When it goes into the form it comes out "1/0/1900".

It seems to be an issue when using a formula in VBA.

```
TestDate = DateAdd("m", 1, "9/1/2018")
ActiveCell = TestDate 'output: 10/1/2018
ActiveCell.Offset(1).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TestDate & "" 'output: 1/0/1900
ActiveCell.Offset(2).Formula = "=" & TestDate & "" 'output: 1/0/1900
```

Comment: You must put the double quotes around your string; e.g. "=(""" & TestDate & """)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotation marks are often a pain in a formula. I don't know what result you're aiming for, but these versions work:

```
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).FormulaR1C1 = "=""" & TestDate & """" 'output: ="10/1/2018"
    ActiveCell.Offset(2).Formula = "=""" & TestDate & """" 'output: ="10/1/2018"
    ActiveCell.Offset(3).FormulaR1C1 = TestDate 'output: 10/1/2018
    ActiveCell.Offset(4).Formula = TestDate 'output: 10/1/2018
```

And here's the official help, [Quotation marks in string expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/criteria-expressions/include-quotation-marks-in-string-expressions).

Comment: This is the best answer, it shows the OP how to fix his problem and provide a link to explain why.

Answer (score 1):

That's what happens when you mix dates and strings..  `TestDate` is stored not as a date, but as a string `9/1/2018`.  When you paste this string into a cell with  your third line `ActiveCell.Offset(1).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TestDate & "" 'output: 1/0/1900`, the output is `=9/1/2018` (0.00445986124876115).  Internally, day 0 is 1/1/1900.  You have to convert your `TestDate` string to a date.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I created a declaration and set it to a date, however, the issue continued. The other post pointed out I was missing the third set of quotation marks... that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Ah - understood...the only way I can get it to work is to do the following. Hope this will work for you!

```
Public Sub Test()

Dim formula As String

ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
TestDate = DateAdd("m", 1, "9/1/2018")
ActiveCell = TestDate
formula = "=Date(" + CStr(Year(TestDate)) + "," + CStr(Month(TestDate)) + "," + CStr(Day(TestDate)) + ")"
ActiveCell.Offset(1).FormulaR1C1 = formula
ActiveCell.Offset(2).formula = formula

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! It requires the "=" to make it a formula, it doesn't matter in this example but in the larger equation it does.

Comment: You're welcome! I just updated the post - see if this will work for you.